# Listview within recycler view load time slow

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

So I have an activity which contains a recyclerview. the recycler viewholder layout contains a textview and a listview in a vertical linear layout (the height is dynamic by the items count and it cant be scrolled for that reason - only the recyclerview can be scrolled).
For now i need to have only 2 of these views and Im pretty sure its going to stay that way.
The problem is that its taking like 3 seconds to load the activity (and fetch the data from the database into the listviews) and I believe its because of the recylcerview way of doing things.

Now I think I have 2 options:

1.Is to do lazy loading. When the scroll is reaching to the end of the content then load the next 50 or 100.

2.Remove the recycler view and just hardcode into the activity

Textview

Listview

Textview

Listview

in that order so it will show like i want it to.
I want to say option 2 is better in this case because its almost certainly not going to change and ill only need to hold two listviews their adapters for them, but again i dont know if its best to just kinda "hardcode" it.

What do you guys think? do you have other suggestions?

Comment: If You only have RecyclerView for 2 elements I think it is not the best option to use it. Maybe You should try to remove "root" RecyclerView and change ListView to RecyclerView

Comment: So you mean stick with the linear layout but instead of the listview change it to textview>recycler>textview>recycler? if so then what benefits does it give me over the listview?

Comment: Why not use only one recyclerview? RecyclerView can allow multiple view types. I don't see any reason why you want to have a vertical listview in a vertical recyclerview

Comment: Yeah, if You load a huge amount of data to this horizontal `ListView` it will faster to load data to `RecyclerView` and set the orientation to horizontal

Comment: Okay bro, got it. let me give it a shot and check if thats work well. I have to say i dont really like to do it this way because the code is less "automated" I guess but its not too too bad because you know its just 2 elements (also pun intented)

Comment: @odifek Im not so familiar with these recyclerviews so I didnt even know thats an option i guess. How can i achieve something like i described in the post with that approach? keep in mind that i have an adapater that displays all the items. can i just add all the views one after another? i really dont know lol

Comment: There is really no need for a ListView inside a ReyclerView.

Comment: What does your listView list_item layout look like?

Comment: Got it all figured out bros, after odifek comment i read some documentation about recyclerviews and implemented a multiview recyclerview (if thats what its called). one thing i do have some problems with is to how to decide when to add the title. for example before i had two lists, one for the user stuff and the second ond is a general list. and now i have combined them to one list. i want a title at the start "User stuff" and when the user stuff ended i added another view "General stuff". so in order to get this i checked the positions. might find something better later, how would you do it?